# Problem of multivariate calculus without using cauchy mean value theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ on $[a,b]$ and differentiable over $(a,b)$. Show that $\exists c\in (a,b)$ such that $(f(b)-f(a))^{\perp}\cdot f'(c)=0$ where $(x,y)^{\perp}=(-y,x)$. Don't use Cauchy Mean Value Theorem.

I know that using Cauchy it is easy but I don't get how to prove it without using. I've been thinking and nothing comes to mind. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\bigl(f(b)-f(a)\bigr)^\perp.f(x)$. Then $g(b)=g(a)$. Therefore, you can apply Rolle's theorem to $g$.